# 1750A Conversion in C-Like language

Tags: c

I am using a custom programming applet in a specific vendor's product that uses a c-like language to perform some arithmetic functions.  Due to this, i have some very quirky limitations to how i get data, and what i can do to process it.  Therefore, I have a strange scenario where i need to convert Mil Std 1750A Float into IEEE754 Float.
I have the Sign bit as an unsigned integer, the 23-bit fraction as an unsigned integer and the 8-bit exponent as an unsigned integer.  I do not have the ability in their language to do any bitwise math or hex.  So I have to try and convert these elements to the equivalent value in IEEE 754.  Once i create the corresponding unsigned integer values of the IEEE 754 Exponent and Fraction, then I have a way to concatenate them together to make an array of 4 bytes (for the 32-bit number).  I know it is a very strange way to implement this, but there are very specific reasons why I have to do it this way.

Can anyone help me with this?

thanks!

Comment: Could you show how you would do the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you know the exact bitwise representation for both the float and the integer on your platform, this may yet be possible:

```
int result = [fraction];
result -= [explicit_MSB_for_normalised_float];
result += [exponent]*[pow(2,exponent_offset_in_float)];
result += [sign]*[pow(2,sign_offset_in_float)];
```

In this case, you don't need bitwise operations, because addition is the same, as long as the numbers you are adding can never have the same bits set. You can replace shifting by multiplication (never thought I'd say that!).
The place this breaks down is denormals. You have to remove the explicit MSB (otherwise it'll muck with the exponent), but what if the number you're converting *doesn't* have the MSB set?
Anyway, finally you'll have to work around strict aliasing to get your result conveted to a frankenfloat.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert a MIL-STD-1750a floating number to a IEEE floating number, and you have an unsigned int for your signed bit, exponent bit, and fractional bit sections? Before we start it is important to understand the specific differences between the Military Standard spec and IEEE. The MIL-STD 1750a is a fixed 16-bit system meant for fast computation of small numbers. This chart should be helpful if you have to collect the values yourself.

[image: Image of bit partition for MIL-std-1750a float]

If you don't already have those isolated values at those positions in the 1750a buffer, then you will need to collect them. So as you said above we will need to apply a mask by addition, or a bit-wise operation by multiplication to collect the signed bit, the 23-bit fraction field, and the 8-bit exponent field.

Since the argument orientation within the Mil-Spec buffer is swapped in comparison to IEEE we will also have to plan accordingly while collecting the fraction, and exponent buffer partitions.

If we have the values, all we will have to do is some sanitation and data computation.

All three of these isolated partitions should then be stored, and used to find the Mantissa, and Exponent field for the final converted float value.

Would seeing some examples in C code help? Does this help you get closer to a solution, if not can I get more context?